# Replacing UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum @selector videoSaved function

Tags: ios, objective-c

- Xcode 7
- Swift 2
- Objective C

I have changed some Objective C code, and I do not know Objective C syntax at all. I have replaced the following code that was saving videos to the camera roll:

```
if ( UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(newPath))
    // Copy it to the camera roll.
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(newPath, self, @selector(videoSaved:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), (__bridge void *)(AvailableVideos[0]));

else
{
    [self ErrorOnDownloadOrSave];
    return;
}
```

With code that is saving the video to the Data Container Document Directory of my app:

```
 NSString *tempFilePath = [downloadURL path];
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Videos"];
    //NSString *newPath = [[tempFilePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:AvailableVideos[0]];
    NSString *newPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:AvailableVideos[0]];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

    //copying temp video to Documents Directory
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:newPath] == YES)
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:newPath error:&error];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:tempFilePath toPath:newPath error:&error];
```

In the Objective C code that is saving to the iOS Camera Roll there is an Objective C "function" that is called when the "videoSaved" event is complete:

```
-(void)videoSaved:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
    //implementation
}
```

I need to figure out how to call this "function", "videoSaved" after this code:

```
  //copying temp video to Documents Directory
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:newPath] == YES)
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:newPath error:&error];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:tempFilePath toPath:newPath error:&error];
```

I realize the `videoSaved` function is a special signature for `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` but I am just so unfamiliar with Objective C that I do not know how to write a new function that I can call, and pass the my error object and maintain the implementation of `videoSaved`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:) documentation, the method `copyItemAtPath` returns BOOL.

> YES if the item was copied successfully or the file manager’s delegate stopped the operation deliberately. Returns NO if an error occurred.

So you can do something like :

```
if ([fileManager copyItemAtPath:tempFilePath toPath:newPath error:&error]) {
      //saved
      NSLog(@"video saved");
} else {
      //error
      NSLog(@"error occured : %@", error);
}
```